# Does contextual serilogger also receive same dependency from Autofac container?

Tags: c#, autofac, serilog

Currently, we are using Serilog together with ApplicationInsights to log the system. One issue we try to solve is attach a unique operation ID to the every log message in a single request. So an error message can be traced.

When build the ILogger for the container

```
serilogConfig.WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsTraces(telemetryClient);
```

The telemtryClient is registerd as instancePerRequest and assigned with a unique OperationID in one of the actionAttribute on the Controller

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var requestScope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
    var telemetryClient = requestScope.GetService(typeof(TelemetryClient)) as TelemetryClient;
    telemetryClient.Context.Operation.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

And inside the constructor of a controller requires logging

```
public ControllerA(ILogger logger)
{
    var contextLogger = logger.ForContext<ControllerA>();
}
```

Now the problem is that the operationID does not appear on the log message.

Even if we register the main ILogger as instancePerRequest, will the contextLogger still getting the same dependency object as the main one?

Comment: Hi Jonathon - how are you registering the logger with Autofac?

Comment: hi @NicholasBlumhardt, my plan is to register it as singleton. however, I am aware of that its not going to work as singleton will not work with dependency with short lifetime. But it feels a little be overkill to register the main ILogger as instancePerRequest, as the logger.ForContext already create a new logger?

Comment: I think you might want a way to set `OperationId` without creating a whole new `TelemetryClient` - then everything could remain registered as singleton. Raising an issue here to that effect might be worthwhile: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt, i have created one issue on applicationinsights site. thanks.